# Initialize model instance without persisting it in database

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to create a waterline model instance so I can later assign values to its properties and call `.save()` on it.
In `lib/waterline/model/lib/model.js` there is a doc comment stating:

`* var Person = Model.prototype;
* var person = new Person({ name: 'Foo Bar' });
* person.name # => 'Foo Bar'`

I have a model User, but I am not able to do any of these statements.

`User.prototype` gives me `undefined` and `var user = new User({firstName: 'Foo'})` gives me an error: `TypeError: User is not a constructor`.
I've read some issues on waterline github, but nothing seems to work for me.

Is there really no way to do this?

EDIT:
this is my current user model definition

```
/**
 * User.js
 *
 * @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
 */

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true,
            alphanumericdashed: true
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        email: {
            type: 'string',
            //email: true,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        lastName: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        company: {
            model: 'company'
        },
        //branches this user can access
        branches: {
            collection: 'branch',
            via: 'users'
        },
        roles: {
            collection: 'userrole',
            via: 'users'
        },
        //array of permission modifying permissions of any of roles assigned to this user
        userPermissions: {
            collection: 'permission',
            via: 'user',
            through: 'userpermission'
        },
        //daily reports this user has been marked in as employee
        dailyReports: {
            collection: 'dailyreport',
            via: 'dailyReportEmployees'
        },
        //events this user has been assigned to
        assignedEvents: {
            collection: 'event',
            via: 'assignees'
        },

        toJSON: function () {
            var obj = this.toObject();

            delete obj.password;

            return obj;
        }
    },

    beforeUpdate: function (values, next) {
        CipherService.hashPassword(values, function () {
            next();
        });
    },
    beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
        CipherService.hashPassword(values, function () {
            next();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: According to the sails doc, all the models should be defined as globals in the sails app. can you attach your User.js file?

Comment: i've added the model definition

Comment: Did you set the models=true in your globals config file: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-globals

Comment: sure, the models are accessible as global variables and i can use them to find, create, update, delete objects from db. the only thing i cannot and should be possible (for reasons mentioned in main post) is `new Model()`. I know this isn't mentioned in the official documentation, but it'd make sense to have some way to initialize waterline model instance